# Deserialize “Zulu” time in ISO8601 format in jackson with 0 to 3 millisecond digits?

Tags: java, json, datetime, jackson, zoneddatetime

I have a need to de-serialize time of format **2016-11-28T10:34:25.097Z** using Jackson into ZonedDateTime of Java8.

I correctly configured ObjectMapper for ZonedDateTime and I have in my code for DTO a field

```
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.[SSS]Z")
private ZonedDateTime updatedAt;
```

The effect of square brackets is to make milliseconds optional as suggested here [Deserialize "Zulu" time in ISO8601 format in jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845843/deserialize-zulu-time-in-iso8601-format-in-jackson).

However, problem is that trailing zeroes are removed by service that sends these, so if I have .100 milliseconds, they come as **2016-11-28T10:34:25.1Z**, if I have .220 miliseconds they will look like **2016-11-28T10:34:25.22Z** so I have in that case **one or two** digits after the dot.

This again violates the format shown above, it only accepts none or all three digits. I tried to use format [S[S[S]]] but it was not good.

How can I specify JSON format so I have anywhere between 0 and 3 millisecond digits?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple optional formats in sequence like this:
`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.[SSS][SS][S]Z"`