# UTC time is being automatically added in my date variable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This my json format :

```
"date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
```

However, in java I received the date as `Wed Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 2020`

The following is the code of my DTO

```
public class DateTimeDto {

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX")
    private Date date;

}
```

I am using `dateTimeDto.getDate()` to receive the date sent in JSON format.

How  can I only get the date without added UTC?

Comment: what do you mean by "in java i am receiving..."? do you see this value in your debugger, or you print your date to std out?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is not ISO-8601 compliant. And in ISO-8601, 'Z' can demote the timezone which is problematic.

Comment: Please read this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845843/deserialize-zulu-time-in-iso8601-format-in-jackson

Comment: how about (sending) `2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:30` (in your json) ...since the translation (UTC -> IST) is correct!

Comment: Use `java.time` instead of `java.util`...

Comment: Note that if you are dealing with this in Java as a `java.util.Date` object: a `Date` object does not know anything about timezones. It will always print itself in your local timezone, if you print it directly. To print it in a different timezone, use a `SimpleDateFormat` object and set the desired timezone on that. Better: Use the `java.time` API instead of the old and crappy `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Welcome to java timezone, so be prepared for a lot of problems and frustrating hours... Don't use the old time api from java, use the new one added from [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) in [JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Comment: @dgebert Yes the value is seen in the logger after I sent the JSON
DEBUG 5436 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(*) from dbo.(table_name) where date = 'Wed Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 2020'

Comment: `java.util.Date` can be seen as a container for a Long that keeps the Epoch milliseconds. If you use it to store a date, and you try to convert it to String (like it happens in your debugger), the date is shown using your current timezone. E.g Date can contain the millisecond X that is Jan 1 10:00:00 GMT but at the same time Jan 1 11:00:00 CET etc. If you need to reconvert it to a String, you must use a formatter, like the one in SimpleDateFormat. So, what is your "real" problem? Put again that date on another JSon, store it on a DB, or what else? Maybe the problem is on another point... :)

Comment: This shows that you probably build the query sending a string and not the object itself. E.g. in your DAO you should have something like
`@Query("select count(x) from TableName x where x.date = :date")`

`public Integer countStuff(@Param("date") Date d);`

PS indeed it is a bad habit to search for an exact date in a db... are you sure that it is exactly what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

> receive the date sent in JSON format.

There is no such thing as a JSON format for date-time values.

> This my json format :

"date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"

The `Z` on the end means this date and time is to be seen as UTC, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. The format of this text is defined in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Parse an an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). Never use `Date`. Use only the *java.time* classes.

Being in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format, there is no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" ) ;
```

So see that moment adjusted into another time zone, apply a `ZoneId`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Know that date-time objects do not have a “format”. You can generate/parse strings in various formats, but the date-time object is separate and distinct.

> only get the date

If you mean the date portion without the time of day, you can extract a `LocalDate` after adjusting into the time zone by which you want to interpret the date. Remember that for any given moment the date various around the globe by zone.

```
Instant
.parse( "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" )
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
.toLocalDate()
```

> without added UTC?

There is no "added" UTC. Your original value represents a moment as seen in UTC. We know that because of the `Z` which means UTC and is pronounced “Zulu”.

> I sent the JSON DEBUG 5436 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL : select count(*) from dbo.(table_name) where date = 'Wed Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 2020'

Use smart object rather than mere strings as the arguments in your queries. Hibernate and JDBC 4.2 allow you to exchange *java.time* objects with your database.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

> 'Wed Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 2020'

Never use that terrible format for exchanging date-time values by text. That format assumes English, is difficult to parse by machine, uses the 2-4 character pseudo-time-zone like `IST` which is not standardized and is not unique (Irish Standard Time? India Standard Time?).

---

Search Stack Overflow for more info. All this has been covered many many times already. Search and study before posting.